# What is the smartest way of creating complex custom themed components with Chakra UI?

Tags: design-patterns, chakra-ui

We want to implement a scalable way of using Chakra UI to create complex custom components with our custom theme styles. But we are finding it difficult to crack which approach would be most scalable.

For instance, let’s say we want to create a ExerciseButton that has a text, an image, and a progress bar that displays how much of the exercise the user has completed

We have thought about different approaches.

1. Create **variant** styles for each of the sub Chakra Ui components.
2. Create a new component, Exercise Button and style its **parts**

Answer (score 0):

Your first option makes sense only if you will reuse those parts and variants for other purposes as well. But even in that case, I would probably still build a custom component using all the correct variants just to minimize developer error.